# @Resource UserTransaction is Null

Tags: java, jta

I have Restful Webservice implementation. Where am maintaining transaction using UserTransaction object by injecting with @Resource. And i could see that UserTransaction object seems to be null. What could be the reason behind this?

```
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;

@Path("User")
    public class UserImpl { 

        @Resource
        private UserTransaction tx;

        @Context
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

     public void doAction() {
          try {
            tx.begin();
            // do the work...
          } finally {
            tx.commit();
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Could you describe your stack/system in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind it is that `UserTransaction` can only be injected to a managed component that supports transactions. The usual component that supports transactions in Java EE is an EJB bean. Annotate your `UserImpl` class with `@Stateless` for that. `UserTransaction` indicates that you want to manually manage your transaction, so you have to tell that the container with `@TransactionManagement`. Like this:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
@Path("User")
public class UserImpl
```

Comment: i have tried with lookup InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
UserTransaction tx = (UserTransaction) ctx.lookup("javax.transaction.UserTransaction"); It worked well, but @resource injection doesn't work here

Comment: @Arun Even with `@Stateless` ?

Comment: No, Am not using EJB here. Earlier i was using EJB project to maintain container based transaction. i was using EJB lookup from rest client to access the EJB object. Noe am trying to do transaction manualy with UserTransaction object. And i maintained transaction manually with above snippet. Now am checking for a solution to inject UserTrasaction using @Resource

Comment: Note: a RESTful JAX-RS service IS a container managed component. It is not only EJBs but basically any tech part of the JEE specification (JSF, JAX-WS, JAX-RS, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Your `UserImpl` does not seem to be `managed`. **Injection only works in container managed objects.** This problem is not specific to injection of `UserTransaction`, but injection in general. As result `HttpServletRequest` is null as well.

Comment: I have the value for object HttpServletRequest but UserTransaction resource is not injected